# Error: itemCount and itemBuilder invalid arguments for ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, github, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0p46.png)

> `

```
child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: categories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => 
            GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                  selectedIndex = index;
                  });
                 },
```

**Arguments itemCount, itemBuilder are now invalid for ListView.builder and child argument is invalid for Positioned widget.**

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpLkd.png
You should be able to use it. Can you create a new widget and write the same code again. If it doesn't work. Save the file and restart the IDE.